# Finding F(x) for Riemann Sum

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

[image]

Not too sure what to do or where to begin. If you guys can help me out that's be great.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what a "Riemann sum" *is*?  A Riemann sun is a sum of the form $\sum f(x_i)\Delta_i$ that approaches the integral $\int f(x)dx$ as the number of partitions goes to infinity.  It should be clear that $\frac{6}{n}$ is constant for all terms and that if you a interval of length 6 into n parts, the length of each part, the $\Delta_i$, for every i, is 6/n.  So the "6/n" part is the "$\Delta_i$".  That means that the remaining part, $\sqrt{8+ \frac{6i}{n}}$ is the "f(x)" part.

Comment: Hmm, it says sqrt(8+(6i/n)) is wrong because variable i is not defined in this context. And also, you're saying the total length is 6/n so are you saying b is 6?